# Definition of scalar field in Kaku, Quantum Field Theory

Tags: representation-theory, classical-field-theory

I just started reading Kaku's book on QFT. In chapter 2, where he is still talking about **classical** fields, he defines the transformation property of a scalar field $\phi(x)$ (equation 2.23) as follows:
$$
U(\theta) \phi(x) U^{-1} (\theta) = \phi(x'),\; U(\theta) = e^{\theta L}, \; L = \left(x^\mu \partial^\nu - x^\nu \partial^\mu \right)
$$

I have two questions about this definition (of which the second is more important):

1. Should $\phi(x')$ not be $\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$ where $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transformation?
2. I do not understand the left hand side: what is $U^{-1} (\theta)$ acting on? I suppose I could insert the trivial identity function after $U^{-1} (\theta)$ and the expression would make sense to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Sloppy mathematics... That is an operatorial equality, i.e. at quantum level (Fock-space operator-valued distributions).

Comment: @DanielC Thank you for the clarification.